# Android: MVVM - RecyclerView dynamic data load

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-livedata

My case is as following: Supposing that I have an app where I show a list of users, and their profile pics (similar to whatsapp).
First I load the list of users, and observer the `LiveData` of users. The problem is, that the url of their profile pic, doesn't come with the `getUsersList` API. Instead, I have to do another network call on fly (while rendering the list), in order to retrieve the profile pic for a given User, let's say `getUserPicByUserId`.

Using, MVVM design pattern, I did this implementation:

1. In **Fragment** class I load the *list of Users* from `getUsersList` API. For each user item, `profilePicUrl` is Null.
2. In **Adapter/ViewHolder** class I check if `profilePicUrl` is **null**. If so, using a listener(`MyAdapterListener`), I do a call to `getUserPic` API for the given User.
3. When the response of `getUserPic` API is ready, I update the user item in **ViewHolder** (see the lambda function `onUrlLoaded: (url: String) -> Unit`) and load the image.

Problems: This approach is causing that all items get the same image, because the observer of `userProfilePicLiveData` is always listening for each user item. And every item will load the last retrieven url.

Adding:

`viewModel.userProfilePicLiveData.removeObservers(lifecycleOwner)` after callback `onUrlLoaded(profilePicUrl)` in **Fragment** will not work either.

I spent some time on this problem, but cannot find a solution.

What would be the appropriate approach for this scenario? How to perform a **network call** when rendering each `RecyclerView` item, and send the result back to the Adapter to update the view?

Here there is the simplified code of what I have done so far:

Model **User**

```
data class User(
  val id: String,
  val name: String,
  val profilePicUrl: String? = null, // By default is null
  ...
)
```

`profilePicUrl` doesn't come with `getUsersList` API, so by default is `Null`.

Model **UserProfilePic**:

```
data class UserProfilePic(
  val url: String
  ...
)
```

Implementation example of **ViewModel** class:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
  val usersListLiveData = LiveData<List<User>>
  val userProfilePicLiveData = LiveData<UserProfilePic>


  fun loadUsers() {
    // Network call...
    usersListLiveData.value = usersList
  }

  fun loadProfilePicByUserId(userId: String) {
    // Network call...
    userProfilePicLiveData.value = userProfilePic
  }

}
```

Adapter class:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(val usersList: List<User>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {

interface MyAdapterListener {
        fun onLoadProfilePicUrl(
            user: User,
            onUrlLoaded: (url: String) -> Unit
        )
    }

class HomeVenueViewHolder(
 val listener: MyAdapterListener
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder() {
      fun bind(user: User) {
        // Fill view list item ...
        
        if (user.profilePicUrl is Null ) {
          listener.onLoadProfilePicUrl(user) { url ->
            user.profilePicUrl = url

            // Load Image From the Url
          }
        } else {
          // Valid url: Load image 
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Fragment class:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment(), MyAdapterListener {

  val viewModel: MyViewModel


  viewModel.usersListLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { usersList ->
    // Setup adapter and show list
  })

  fun loadUsers() {
    viewModel.loadUsers()
  }

  override fun onLoadProfilePicUrl(
      user: User,
      onUrlLoaded: (url: String) -> Unit
  ) {
    viewModel.loadProfilePicByUserId(user.id)

    viewModel.userProfilePicLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { profilePicUrl ->
      // This is a callback to Adapter
       onUrlLoaded(profilePicUrl)
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: why does your api return a user without their picture ? that doesn't seem like a complete user object, probably irrelevant to your question

Comment: @a_local_nobody There is nothing to do for that. The service is offered by a 3rd party and I have to find a solution with these restrictions.

Comment: Why not just wait until you've done both API calls before sending the data to the Adapter?

Comment: @GavinWright In what way? I tried to do this in `Interceptor` layer. Iterating in each user and doing a `getProfilePic` for each user to complete the `User` object. But this added to much delay... Is there a better workaround for this?

Comment: @user677767 I have the similar issue, can you please post the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel should update the list stored in `usersListLiveData` every time `loadProfilePicByUserId(userId: String)` pulls a new profile image from the API. Your Fragment should observe `usersListLiveData` and notify the adapter when the data changes (using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` or an equivalent).

One caveat is that `User` is a complex object, and `usersListLiveData` is a list of these complex objects. You can't get away with just changing the one property `profilePicUrl` in the relevant list item. You need to call something like `usersListLiveData.value = newUserList`or else the observer of the MutableLiveData won't fire. Observers won't fire when you just change a single property of a complex object. You need to call `setValue()` or `postValue()`.